# What is a runtime error?

Tags: python, pygame, windows-vista, compatibility, cx-freeze

I made a game with Python 2.6. I also made it into an executable with cx_Freeze 4.3. When I run the executable on my computer it came up with this:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Program: C:\Users\smm\Desktop\asteroid shower 1.4.5\asteroid.exe


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I don't understand what happened here. I tried solving the problem but with no luck. Then I searched the runtime error on google and it said it might be the compatibility. I wrote the original script on windows vista with the downloaded version of the windows 7 python 2.6. I did this because the windows vista had no internet so I downloaded the python, pygame and cx_freeze .msi files on my windows 7 laptop. Then I transferred the files to the desktop windows vista. Is this the problem? Or maybe the script? I don't think its the script as I can play the game when it is still a python script. Its a bit long though... I running windows 7 with python 2.6, pygame 2.6 and cx_freeze 4.3. Thanks if you can help me :).

```
    # By Sandy Goetjens
# Asteroid Shower V1.4.5

import pygame, random, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = BLACK
FPS = 40
ASTEROIDCIRCLESPEED = 1
ASTEROIDMINSIZE = 10
ASTEROIDMAXSIZE = 40
ASTEROIDMINSPEED = 1
ASTEROIDMAXSPEED = 8
ADDNEWASTEROIDRATE = 10
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5
TOKENSIZE = 20
TOKENSPEED = 8
ADDNEWTOKENRATE = 6
BULLETSPEED = 3
BULLETFIRETIME = 1000
BULLETSIZE = 20
GHOSTSIZE = 20
GHOSTSPEED = 5
ADDNEWGHOSTRATE = 8
HEALTHSIZE = 20
HEALTHSPEED = 10
ADDNEWHEALTHRATE = 9
EYEBALLSIZE = 20
EYEBALLSPEED = 15
ADDNEWARROWRATE = 5
ARROWSIZE = 10
ARROWSPEED = 18
ADDNEWDUSTRATE = 8
DUSTSIZE = 12
DUSTSPEED = 16
ADDNEWEYEBALLRATE = 10
GHOSTSIZE = 20
GHOSTSPEED = 10
ADDNEWGHOSTRATE = 15
NEWASTEROIDSPEED = 30

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitHealth(playerRect, healths):
    for h in healths:
        if playerRect.colliderect(h['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawAsteroidRotation(ASTEROIDCIRCLESPEED, rotation, asteroids):
    for a in asteroids:
        left = leftCordinOfAsteroid
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, (left, ASTEROIDSIZE, ASTEROIDSIZE))
        pygame.display.update()

def asteroidAnimation(asteroids):
    for rotation in asteroids(ASTEROIDCIRCLESPEED):
        drawAsteroidRotation(ASTEROIDCIRCLESPEED, rotation, asteroids)

def bulletHasHitAsteroid(bulletRect, asteroids):
    for b in bullets:
        if bulletRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            bombExplosion.play()
            return True
            bombExplosion.stop()
    return False

def playerHasHitToken(playerRect, tokens):
    for t in tokens:
        if playerRect.colliderect(t['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, asteroids):
    for a in asteroids:
        if playerRect.colliderect(a['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def playerHasHitGhost(playerRect, ghosts):
    for g in ghosts:
        if playerRect.colliderect(g['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def playerHasHitEyeball(playerRect, eyeballs):
    for e in eyeballs:
        if playerRect.colliderect(e['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def playerHasHitArrow(playerRect, arrows):
    for r in arrows:
        if playerRect.colliderect(r['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def playerHasHitDust(playerRect, dusts):
    for d in dusts:
        if playerRect.colliderect(d['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def asteroidHasHitBullet(baddieRect, bullets):
    for a in asteroids:
        if asteroidRect.collierect(a['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 48)
    textobj = font.render(text, 10, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def version(font, windowSurface, versionbackgroundImage):
    while True:
        windowSurface.blit(versionBackgroundImage, (0, 0))
        drawText('Buy the full game to play more', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 200, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) - 200)
        drawText('levels!! Plus bonus', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 200, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) - 150)
        drawText('updates and new game', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 200, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) - 100)
        drawText('releases!! Presented', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 200, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) - 50)
        drawText('by Desert Labotories', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 200, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) - 0)
        pygame.display.update()
        waitForPlayerToPressKey()
        return

def Credits(font, windowSurface, creditbackgroundImage):
    while True:
        windowSurface.blit(creditBackgroundImage, (0, 0))
        drawText('Created by Sandy Goetjens', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 150, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
        drawText('Presented by Desert Labortories', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 150, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 100)
        pygame.display.update()
        waitForPlayerToPressKey()
        return

def waitForPlayerToEnterKeys():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escapes quits
                    terminate()
                if event.key == K_c:
                    Credits(font, windowSurface, creditBackgroundImage)
                if event.key == K_x:
                    version(font, windowSurface, versionBackgroundImage)
                return

def Level3(font, windowSurface, level):
    while True:
        drawText('Buy the full version to', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 150, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
        drawText('continue playing!', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 150, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
        drawText('8 new and challenging levels!', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 150, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3 + 100))
        pygame.display.update()
        waitForPlayerToPressKey()
        return

def Level1(font, windowSurface, level, applauseSound):
    while True:
        applauseSound.play()
        drawText('LEVEL 1 completed!', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 100, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
        drawText('Press a key to continue.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 100, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
        drawText('By Sandy Goetjens.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 100, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 150)
        drawText('RATE US ON FACEBOOK', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 100, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 200)
        drawText('Entering BLUE LANDS', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 100, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 250)
        pygame.display.update()
        applauseSound.stop()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                if True:
                    level = 2
                    kilometres = 3000
                    return


# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
global level, kilometres
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('asteroid.icon'))
pygame.display.set_caption('Asteroid Shower Demo V1.4.5')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')
bombExplosion = pygame.mixer.Sound('explosion-01.wav')
warnSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('alarm02.wav')
applauseSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('applause2.wav')

# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('asteroid.png')
baddieRect = baddieImage.get_rect()
tokenImage = pygame.image.load('tokens.png')
bulletImage = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletRect = bulletImage.get_rect()
ghostImage = pygame.image.load('ghosts.png')
healthImage = pygame.image.load('health.png')
eyeballImage = pygame.image.load('eyeball.png')
arrowImage = pygame.image.load('arrow.png')
dustImage = pygame.image.load('dust.png')
versionBackgroundImage = pygame.image.load('background.png')
creditBackgroundImage = pygame.image.load('creditsbackground.png')

creditsPage = pygame.image.load('credits.png')
desertLabs = pygame.image.load('desert labs.png')

# show the "Start" screen
windowSurface.blit(creditsPage, (0, 0))
pygame.time.wait(1000)
drawText('Asteroid Shower ', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 4 - 100))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 4 - 50))
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToEnterKeys()

level = 0
bullet = 50
token = 0
topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    tokens = []
    asteroids = []
    bullets = []
    eyeballs = []
    arrows = []
    dusts = []
    ghosts = []
    healths = []
    score = 0
    health = 100
    kilometres = 2500
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    asteroidAddCounter = 0
    ghostAddCounter = 0
    tokenAddCounter = 0
    healthAddCounter = 0
    eyeballAddCounter = 0
    arrowAddCounter = 0
    dustAddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score
        kilometres -= 1 # decrease kilomteres

        if level == 0:
            if kilometres == 0:
                level = 2
                kilometres = 3000
                Level1(font, windowSurface, level, applauseSound)

        # Go to level 3 title
        if level == 2 and kilometres == 0:
            Level3(font, windowSurface, level)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True
                if event.key == K_z:
                    if token > 500:
                        token -= 500
                        if bullet < 200:
                            bullet += 50
                if event.key == K_x:
                    if token > 600:
                        token -= 600

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

            if token > 0:
                if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    # If player clicks mouse bullets will fire
                    if bullet > 0:
                        bullet -= 1
                        newBullet = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-BULLETSIZE), 0 - BULLETSIZE, BULLETSIZE, BULLETSIZE),
                                     'speed': (BULLETSPEED),
                                     'surface':pygame.transform.scale(bulletImage, (BULLETSIZE, BULLETSIZE)),
                                     }

                        bullets.append(newBullet)

        # Add new tokens at the top of the screen, if needed
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            tokenAddCounter += 1
        if tokenAddCounter == ADDNEWTOKENRATE:
            tokenAddCounter = 0
            newToken = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-TOKENSIZE), 0 - TOKENSIZE, TOKENSIZE, TOKENSIZE),
                        'speed': (TOKENSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(tokenImage, (TOKENSIZE, TOKENSIZE)),
                        }

            tokens.append(newToken)

        if level == 0:
            # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                asteroidAddCounter += 1
            if asteroidAddCounter == ADDNEWASTEROIDRATE:
                asteroidAddCounter = 0
                asteroidSize = random.randint(ASTEROIDMINSIZE, ASTEROIDMAXSIZE)
                newAsteroid = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-asteroidSize), 0 - asteroidSize, asteroidSize, asteroidSize),
                               'speed': random.randint(ASTEROIDMINSPEED, ASTEROIDMAXSPEED),
                               'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (asteroidSize, asteroidSize)),
                               }

                asteroids.append(newAsteroid)

        if level == 0:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                ghostAddCounter += 1
            if ghostAddCounter == ADDNEWGHOSTRATE:
                ghostAddCounter = 0
                newGhost = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-GHOSTSIZE), 0 - GHOSTSIZE, GHOSTSIZE, GHOSTSIZE),
                            'speed': (GHOSTSPEED),
                            'surface': pygame.transform.scale(ghostImage, (GHOSTSIZE, GHOSTSIZE)),
                            }

                ghosts.append(newGhost)

        if health < 50:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                healthAddCounter += 1
            if healthAddCounter == ADDNEWHEALTHRATE:
                healthAddCounter = 0
                newHealth = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-HEALTHSIZE), 0 - HEALTHSIZE, HEALTHSIZE, HEALTHSIZE),
                             'speed': (HEALTHSPEED),
                             'surface': pygame.transform.scale(healthImage, (HEALTHSIZE, HEALTHSIZE)),
                             }

                healths.append(newHealth)

        if level == 2:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                eyeballAddCounter += 1
            if eyeballAddCounter == ADDNEWEYEBALLRATE:
                eyeballAddCounter = 0
                newEyeball = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-EYEBALLSIZE), 0 - EYEBALLSIZE, EYEBALLSIZE, EYEBALLSIZE),
                              'speed': (EYEBALLSPEED),
                              'surface': pygame.transform.scale(eyeballImage, (EYEBALLSIZE, EYEBALLSIZE)),
                              }

                eyeballs.append(newEyeball)

        if level == 2:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                arrowAddCounter += 1
            if arrowAddCounter == ADDNEWARROWRATE:
                arrowAddCounter = 0
                newArrow = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-ARROWSIZE), 0 - ARROWSIZE, ARROWSIZE, ARROWSIZE),
                            'speed': (ARROWSPEED),
                            'surface': pygame.transform.scale(arrowImage, (ARROWSIZE, ARROWSIZE)),
                            }

                arrows.append(newArrow)

        if level == 2:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                dustAddCounter += 1
            if dustAddCounter == ADDNEWDUSTRATE:
                dustAddCounter = 0
                newDust = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-DUSTSIZE), 0 - DUSTSIZE, DUSTSIZE, DUSTSIZE),
                           'speed': (DUSTSPEED),
                           'surface': pygame.transform.scale(dustImage, (DUSTSIZE, DUSTSIZE)),
                           }

                dusts.append(newDust)

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for a in asteroids:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, a['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for a in asteroids[:]:
            if a['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                asteroids.remove(a)

        for g in ghosts:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                g['rect'].move_ip(0, g['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                g['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                g['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

        # Delete each ghost that have fallen past the bottom
        for g in ghosts[:]:
            if g['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                ghosts.remove(g)

        # Move the tokens down
        for t in tokens:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                t['rect'].move_ip(0, t['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                t['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                t['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

        # Delete each token that have fallen past the bottom
        for t in tokens[:]:
            if t['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                tokens.remove(t)

        # Move bullets down
        for b in bullets:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat: 
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

        for b in bullets[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                bullets.remove(b)

        # Move health down
        for h in healths:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                h['rect'].move_ip(0, h['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                h['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                h['rect'].move_ip(0, -1)

        for h in healths[:]:
            if h['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                healths.remove(h)

        # Move eyeballs down
        for e in eyeballs:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                e['rect'].move_ip(0, e['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                e['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                e['rect'].move_ip(0, -1)

        for e in eyeballs[:]:
            if e['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                eyeballs.remove(e)

        for r in arrows:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                r['rect'].move_ip(0, r['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                r['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                r['rect'].move_ip(0, -1)

        for r in arrows[:]:
            if r['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                arrows.remove(r)

        for d in dusts:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                d['rect'].move_ip(0, d['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                d['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                d['rect'].move_ip(0, -1)

        for d in dusts[:]:
            if d['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                dusts.remove(d)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        if level == 2:
            windowSurface.fill(BLUE)

        # Draw the score top score, token, how many bombs, health and how much boss life
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)
        drawText('Token: %s' % (token), font, windowSurface, 10, 80)
        drawText('Bombs: %s' % (bullet), font, windowSurface, 10, 120)
        drawText('Km: %s' % (kilometres), font, windowSurface, 10, 160)
        drawText('Health: %s' % (health), font, windowSurface, 10, 560)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Check the score to enter the next level

        # Draw each asteroid
        for a in asteroids:
            windowSurface.blit(a['surface'], a['rect'])

        for g in ghosts:
            windowSurface.blit(g['surface'], g['rect'])

        # Draw each token
        for t in tokens:
            windowSurface.blit(t['surface'], t['rect'])

        # Draw each bullet
        for b in bullets:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        # Draw each health
        for h in healths:
            windowSurface.blit(h['surface'], h['rect'])

        # Draw each eyeball
        for e in eyeballs:
            windowSurface.blit(e['surface'], e['rect'])

        # Draw each arrow
        for r in arrows:
            windowSurface.blit(r['surface'], r['rect'])

        # Draw each dust
        for d in dusts:
            windowSurface.blit(d['surface'], d['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the health have hit the player
        if playerHasHitHealth(playerRect, healths):
            health += 5
            if health < 100:
                health -= 0
            healths.remove(h)

        # Cheack if any of the eyeballs have hit the player
        if playerHasHitEyeball(playerRect, eyeballs):
            health -= 10
            if health == 0:
                if score > topScore:
                    topScore = score
                break

        # Check if any of the arrows have hit the player
        if playerHasHitArrow(playerRect, arrows):
            health -= 15
            if health == 0:
                if score > topScore:
                    topScore = score
                break

        # Check if any of the dusts have hit the player
        if playerHasHitDust(playerRect, dusts):
            health -= 5
            if health == 0:
                if score > topScore:
                    topScore = score
                break

        # Check if any of the bullets have hit asteroids.
        if bulletHasHitAsteroid(bulletRect, asteroids):
            score += 1000
            if True:
                for a in asteroids:
                    if a['rect'].colliderect:
                        asteroids.remove(a)

        # Check if any of the tokens have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitToken(playerRect, tokens):
            score += 10
            token += 1

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, asteroids):
                health -= 5
                if health == 0:
                    if score > topScore:
                        topScore = score # set new top score
                    break

        if playerHasHitGhost(playerRect, ghosts):
                health -= 10
                if health == 0:
                    if score > topScore:
                        topScore = score # set new top score
                    break

        if health == 0:
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: Searching for `pygame cx_freeze` brings up many previous questions. Have you gone through them already?

Comment: What previous questions?

Comment: Use search field (see top right corner on the page) to search `cx_Freeze runtime` and you get link to question `Pygame Distribution - Runtime Error` - maybe with answer to your problem

Comment: That is a lot of constants. Maybe you want to make a class to manage them, to make it cleaner?

Answer (score 6):

A run time error is a type of error that is deliberately raised during program run time (hence the name). For example, in python, a runtime error can only occur when someone writes

```
raise RuntimeError
```

This is meant to be a way to stop the program if there is a type of error that the program interpreter has not detected, but is capable of causing the program to not function as it has to. An example of when a runtime error is required is this function (a wrapper for the termcolor cprint function that takes a number as its color argument):

```
import termcolor

def coloredprint(text,color):
    if color == 1:
        termcolor.cprint(text,color='red')
    if color == 2:
        termcolor.cprint(text,color='green')
```

In this circumstance, the function will fail to run properly or inform the user of any kind of error if the color argument is not 1 or 2. The way to solve this, and make your program easier to use, is a runtime error (or larger libraries will create their own custom exceptions, this is not important). Basically, because an argument other than 1 or 2 is in fact an error in your program (that python won't catch and raise for you), it will raise an error for the user to diagnose. Here is the new and better version of the function:

```
import termcolor

def coloredprint(text,color):
    if color == 1:
        termcolor.cprint(text,color='red')
    if color == 2:
        termcolor.cprint(text,color='green')
    else:
        print "colored print function: color argument", color, "is not a viable argument, specify 1 or 0"
        raise RuntimeError
```

Now, if the user makes a mistake, the program will catch this as an error, instead of failing to function or doing something unexpected, which would make it difficult to diagnose (and in some cases potentially vulnerable). This is why a runtime error is useful.

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant. The "Runtime Error" the questioner is getting is not a Python error as far as I can tell, but a Windows error message from the frozen `.exe`.

Comment: Did you ment `elif` instead of second `if`?

Comment: This should be ValueError.

Answer (score -1):

Runtime exceptions means some fault logic that caused your running program to terminate abruptly. since, you didn't write any logic to handle them, it resulted into a runtime exception.